# Printout values in dropdown list received from arraylist

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I am doing some frontend form for my we application which will manage home incomes and outcomes (home budget).
To add specific `income`, user must select `incomeCategory` for example: salary/selling/gift etc.
While preparing income form in *HTML* I would like to print `incomeCategory` as a dropdown List to let user select one of available choses.
The list is received from backend service and it's arrayList.
The problem which I'm facing is to printout description value of `incomeCategory` object in dropdown list. Every tutorials which I have found was hardcoded ones like:

```
<select name="carlist" form="carform">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

What I've tried to do is:

```
<div><label for="incomeCategory" >Category:</label>
                <select name="incomeCategory" form="incomeCategory">
                    <tr th:each="temp :${incomeCategories}">
                        <option value="${temp}" >${temp.description}</option>
                    </tr>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" id="incomeCategory"/>
</div>
```

I would like to do something what you see in 4th line. 
incomeCategory class has two attributes:

```
public class IncomeCategory{

    private Long id;
    private String description;
// constructor, getters, setters
}
```

At this time loop over categories works fine while I got 3 items in my list: 
[image]

Is there any possibility using HTML and Thymeleaf to printout categories description in a dropdownList?
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your code, you do not set a `th:text` attribute and thymeleaf renders the text in the `<option>` tag (which is ${temp.description}) as text. You should use a `th:text` thymeleaf attribute to let thymeleaf know that it is a dynamic value. Also on the `th:value` you have set the object reference (temp), you should use temp.id instead.

Assuming that you already pass the incomeCategories List as a Model Attribute in your controller, change your option tag as the following

```
<option value="Sample" th:each="temp :${incomeCategories}" 
th:value="${temp.id}" th:text="${temp.description}">Sample Description</option>
```

Using Thymeleaf, you can loop inside the  tag. I added the Sample and Sample Description text so you can render a drop down list by just loading the HTML page in a browser without having to pass through a servlet container.